Removing mongoDB from MacOS
I need to delete all mongoDB thing in my mac.
i followed the uninstall guide on mongoDB uninstall official guide
but on step 2 which is
`launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
rm -f ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community`

i got this error:
Unload failed: 5: Input/output error Try running "launchctl bootout" as root for richer errors. 

I have successfully uninstalled guys. For Apple Sillicon users, brew prefix is set to /opt/homebrew/etc/ insted of /usr/local/.
So what i did is cd /opt/homebrew/ then ls it.
i found related folders/files with mongodb. i used rm -rf to removed them.
